# 14.10 Windows home network connection keeps asking for password

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, windows

I have a home network on a HP Media Smart Server with Windows Home Server OS and a HTPC with Ubuntu 14.10.

Everything is working great with the exception that **I cannot access my home network.**

When I go to files, browse network the Ubuntu machine sees the Home Server and the other computer running Windows 7 but when I enter my password it will not connect. It brings back the password screen and says a password is required.

I have double checked the password and even reset it but it still will not connect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the Ubuntu username/password identical to the Windows username/password?

Comment: HOw would I check this I have the Ubuntu computer setup with one user admin with no password required to logon and that user name is the same as a user profile on the HP server.

Comment: "no password required" actually *has* a password, but *really complicated*  and generated and used by Ubuntu internally...  You definitely don't want that! Ensure both user names and passwords are *identical*.

Comment: Thanks Fabby23 I changed my user password on the server and was able to get connected. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't thank me, I'll add it as an answer instead of a comment. Just accept the answer and upvote it!  That's the best thank you you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses something called "shadow passwords" to allow access to windows shares if you're not connected to a corporate LAN.

**Just ensure that the user name and password on your Ubuntu machine are identical to the one on your Windows machine**

(or alternatively if you have a need for multiple users to connect to that share: define all users on the Windows machine as well and add their user names to the Access Control List of the Windows share!)